# Extract substring from one index to another index

Tags: vb.net, substring

VB.NET has a `Substring` method that takes the starting index and the length of the substring as parameters. Is it possible to extract a substring from one index to another (instead of using length)?

For example, if I had a string `"1 + 1 = 2"`, and I wanted to extract everything between the `+` and the `=` I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
string.Substring(string.IndexOf("+") + 1, string.IndexOf("=") - 1)
```

The reason I don't want to use length is because I'm unsure how many digits the number will be between the `+` and the `=`.

Is Regex my only option or am I missing something simple?

Comment: `string.Substring(string.IndexOf("+") + 1, string.Length -  string.IndexOf("="))`

Comment: This was returning the wrong data. It would cut off the integers if they were over 3 digits and would also include the = sign for some reason. @Martin Soles had the right answer. Thanks for commenting though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have all the pieces to figure out the length of the substring you want. You know where the two end points are. From that, you can calculate the number of characters that you need to take.

```
Dim Value = "1 + 1 = 2"
Dim Start = Value.IndexOf("+") + 1 '3 in this example
Dim Last = Value.IndexOf("=") - 1 '5 in this example
Dim Length = Last - Start + 1 '5 - 3 + 1 = 3
Dim Result = Value.SubString(Start, Length)
```

Comment: It's so simple I can't believe how I didn't see this. I often look too hard at the simple problems. Thanks!